# Getting image from iPhone gallery created on specific date

Tags: ios

I want to display all the images from image gallery which are created on a particular date.Is it possible?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Can u please suggest the way by which I can do this? Any link if you like to mention.

Comment: @userXXX have a look at the ALAssetLibrary class' documentation.

Comment: It would be great if I can get any working link related to this. It would be really great help for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)loadImagelist{
  void (^assetEnumerator)(ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *theAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    if(theAsset != NULL) {
      NSString *date = [theAsset valueForProperty: ALAssetPropertyDate];
      //if date == xxx add to list
    }
  };

  void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
      if(group != nil) {
        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
    }
  };

  ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
  [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
      NSLog(@"Failure");
  }];
}
```